# Deleting an unnamed column from a csv file Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, file

I ma trying to write a code that deletes the unnamed column `,` that comes right before `Unix Timestamp`. After deleting I will save the modified `dataframe` into `data.csv`. How would I be able to get the Expected Output below?

```
import pandas ads pd 

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.drop('')
data.to_csv('data.csv')
```

data.csv file

```
,Unix Timestamp,Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
0,1635686220,2021-10-31 13:17:00,BTCUSD,60638.0,60640.0,60636.0,60638.0,0.4357009185659157
1,1635686160,2021-10-31 13:16:00,BTCUSD,60568.0,60640.0,60568.0,60638.0,3.9771881707839967
2,1635686100,2021-10-31 13:15:00,BTCUSD,60620.0,60633.0,60565.0,60568.0,1.3977284440628714
```

Updated csv (Expected Output):

```
Unix Timestamp,Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
1635686220,2021-10-31 13:17:00,BTCUSD,60638.0,60640.0,60636.0,60638.0,0.4357009185659157
1635686160,2021-10-31 13:16:00,BTCUSD,60568.0,60640.0,60568.0,60638.0,3.9771881707839967
1635686100,2021-10-31 13:15:00,BTCUSD,60620.0,60633.0,60565.0,60568.0,1.3977284440628714
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the index. Use `index=False` in `to_csv`.

```
data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: it places the indexes as a column  `Unamed: 0` at the end of the csv file. Solution does not work

Comment: @georgehere please provide a minimal example

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the issue, `data.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)` unfortunately resulted in that

Answer (score 0):

Set the first column as index `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)` and set `index=False` when writing the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below code.it will take column from 1st position and then you can save that df to csv without index values.

```
df = df.iloc[:,1:]
df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False)
```